# Check user account in an SP group is disabled or not

Tags: 2010, powershell, active-directory

I have this piece of PowerShell script that lists out all the users in a SharePoint group

```
...
foreach ($grp in $web.groups) { 
  $grp.name 
  foreach ($user in $grp.users) {
    "  User: " + $user.name
  }
}
...
```

This results in the following:

```
Test Group 1
  User: Doe, John
  User: Smith, Robert
  User: DOMAIN\someusername
Test Group 2
  User: DOMAIN\anotherusername
...
```

How would I check if the user's account is disabled or not?

I figured I'd need to user `Get-AdUser` in some way, but I'm not sure how to correctly pass `$user.name` or `$user` as a parameter to it.

Comment: Better use $user.LoginName, as your environment is not Claims-authenticated, that should suffice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SPUser.LoginName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spuser.loginname.aspx) is the property you can map to ActiveDirectory sAMAccountName LDAP attribute. Use serverfault.com or TechNet Gallery for further inquiries on how to use DOMAIN\Username logins and ADSI to query AD.